# Disable tooltips in Chrome DevTools Sources tab

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, tooltip, breakpoints

With Chrome DevTools open I can place a breakpoint in a Javascript file and step through the code displayed in the "Sources" tab as it executes. The problem is that every time I hover over a variable I get an unwanted tooltip that pops up with the value of that variable.

For example if a section of code is `let a = 1;` then any time my cursor happens to pass over `a` I get a popup displaying `1`.  Some variables such as DOM elements can be quite large and frequently get in the way as I am trying to look at the code. I find this annoying and would like to disable this feature. Is there a way to NEVER see these tooltips?